# my highly nested foreach logic works upon first iteration only

Tags: php

I have some nested foreach loops and I get funny and unexpected results.

On line 9 in my example code below, I am looping over "$servers as $server" and upon the first iteration of the main loop, it all works fine, I get the list of servers as expected, but for subsequent iterations, I don't.

The condition on line 7 however keeps returning true when it should "if ($synced['video_id'] == $v['id'])".

This leads me to ask - the array I call $servers - is it somehow used up after the first iteration, or do I need to reset it back to position 0 again for some reason?

```
    //create array of servers synced with this video, also count them for later percentage readout.
    foreach ($videos as &$v) {
        $syncArray = Array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($synced as $synced) {
            //find whether sync-entity pertains to this video
            if ($synced['video_id'] == $v['id']) {
                //now get name of synched server instead of id
                foreach($servers as $server) {
                    if ( $synced['server_id'] == $server['id'] ) {
                        $syncArray[$i] = $server['screenName'];
                        //if servers screen has a parent, put that in parenthesis for clarity
                        if ($server['screenParent']) {
                            $syncArray[$i] .= " (". $server['screenParent'] .")";
                        }                           
                    }
                }
                //increment for calculating percentage later
                $i++;
            }
        }
        //append the array of synced servers for this video to the videoarray
        $v['syncArray'] = $syncArray;
```

var_dump of $servers:

```
array(3) {
[0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(9) ["userName"]=> string(20) "företag1/testskärm" ["screenName"]=> string(9) "Gate C 22" ["screenParent"]=> string(10) "Terminal 5" }
[1]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(15) ["userName"]=> string(15) "företag1/entre" ["screenName"]=> string(6) "Entré" ["screenParent"]=> string(14) "Avgångshallen" }
[2]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(17) ["userName"]=> string(14) "företag1/test" ["screenName"]=> string(4) "test" ["screenParent"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Comment: `foreach ($synced as $synced)` use different variable names for the array you are iterating over and each member

Comment: My initial question would be, what is defined in $servers? Are you sure its not a single item, thus explaining the single iteration? Add a print_r line beforehand to confirm that is the case.

Comment: I changed foreach ($synced as $synced) as suggested to have different names and it works now, thanks. Can't check off a comment as THE answer thought?

Comment: @MattiasSvensson: Technically there is not really an answer to your question. You wrote this question because you made a little mistake (these things can happen). I tried to show with my answer a way how you can reduce making mistakes to a certain amount.

Comment: Well in my case I had an error at ($synced as $synced) when I fixed that it all worked out fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a good example why a programming language allows you to write functions and objects.

For example, how does this look like?

```
//create array of servers synced with this video, also count them for later percentage readout.
foreach ($videos as &$v) {
    $v['syncArray'] = get_synched_video_array_by_id($synched, $v['id']);
}
```

That was the first level of your nested foreach operation. Now imagine the next levels. See http://php.net/functions

The less nesting processings and conditions you have, the less complex is your code. Reducing the complexity reduces the amount of errors that can happen and how hard these errors are to track.

This should also easily solve your concrete problem of variable re-use (quoting *Asad*):

> `foreach ($synced as $synced)` use different variable names for the array you are iterating over and each member

Comment: I will try and break it down, good idéa. I usually do when it becomes too bad but this was only a few levels ;-)

Comment: Not only that, you can also provide a function that filters an array based on a simple comparison condition. You use that two times in your code for example. This could also make it easier for you. Breaking things down is a very good way to handle programming problems btw.